# If default type of Java integer literal is type int, why does these assignment statements compile?

Tags: java

I know this for literals in java, **the default type of java integer literal is type int and the default type of java decimal literal is type double**, but there is a point that confuses my mind.Why the following integer codes is compile while the decimal codes is not compile ?

I don't understand why shortValue, byteValue and charValue assignments are compiled ?

```
short shortValue = 2; // Compile
byte byteValue = 1;   // Compile
char charValue = 123; // Compile
long longValue = 123; // Compile

float floatValue = 2;     // Compile
float floatValue2 = 2.0;  // Does Not Compile
float floatValue3 = 2.0f; // Compile

double doubleValue = 2;    // Compile
double doubleValue2 = 2.0; // Compile
```

Comment: because it is explicitly allowed in the Java Language Specification [JLS-5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2-200)

Comment: More precisely, the reason is that of all the lines in your question, the one that won't compile is the only one that could generally lose information. Because many floating point values can't be represented exactly, you'll have a better approximation in those cases if you store the approximation in a double vs a float.  When you assign a double to a float, you lose that extra precision and so you lose information.  I don't know how much work it would be for Java to know that `2.0` can be represented exactly, where `3.0` can't and so allow the former but not the latter, but it doesn't do that.

Comment: NB These are not assignments. These are iniitalizations. Special rules apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler knows that the numbers you are using is small enough and can therefore fit into the given space. If you do `short d = 1000000;` it cannot fit in a short and will give you an error.